# jQuery change html on clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click I am copying a div. I wish to alter some of the html and then append.

I have tried the following, it will clone and append but I cant seem to alter the html. Not sure what is the best way to handle it, i am sure I have it wrong.

thanks

```
var htmlStr = $(this).parents(".listingContainer").first();
$htmlStr.find(".saveCompareShow").remove()
$(htmlStr).clone().appendTo('.compareWrapper');
```

Comment: Are you perchance trying to edit the cloned html via some kind of id attribute that may no longer uniquely identify an element, now that its a clone?

Comment: sorry should have been clearer, .saveCompareShow is a div with the outter that is copied, it is there alright. I am just using the incorrect syntax to find it. The error In firebug is $htmlStr is not defined

Comment: Heads-up: you are referencing an undefined variable on the second line.

Comment: "htmlStr" and "$htmlStr" are different variables

Comment: Post the HTML and show the after state you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have cloned a DOM element you should treat it just as though you wanted to change a DOM element that isn't being cloned.  You just use your variable instead of a selector.

Assuming that you have HTML like this:

```
​<div class='listingContainer'>
    <div class='listing'>
        Something
    </div>
    <div class='listing'>
        Another something
    </div>
</div>
```

You can clone the contents of the listingContainer DIV and change the contents before appending them to the compareWrapper div.  The following JavaScript shows a simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.listing').click(function() {
        var $htmlStr = $(this).parents(".listingContainer").first();
        $htmlStr.clone().find('.listing').html('<li>Cloned</li>').appendTo('.compareWrapper');
    });
});
```

I've also posted a jsFiddle so you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/hkBMK/

Answer (score 2):

After cloning, you can treat the object just as if it was html already in the dom.

For example - html on your page:

```
<div id="cloneHere"></div>
<div class="well" id="buildInfoTemplate">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend></legend>
          <label></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
          <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>

          <button class="btn">Save</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Lets say you wanted to change the help-block text:

```
var template = $('#buildInfoTemplate').clone().removeAttr('id');
$('.help-block',template).html('hi there ryan');
$('#cloneHere').append(template);
```

And you'll get:

```
<div id="cloneHere">
  <div class="well">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend></legend>
          <label></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
          <span class="help-block">hi there ryan</span>

          <button class="btn">Save</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

so your variable htmlStr is actually an element, not a string.  but that is ok.  I think you need to do this on the second line:

```
htmlStr.remove(".saveCompareShow");
```

If I see correcly, you are trying to remove elements with the class ".saveCompareShow" from the htmlStr element.  Is that right?

** EDIT **

Try this to replace both line 2 and 3

```
$(htmlStr).clone().remove(".saveCompareShow").appendTo('.compareWrapper');
```

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work. I see that you use htmlStr instead of my $htmlStr and that did work but it removed the class from both the original and the cloned

Comment: @KeithPower -  See my edit, yes the original solution I gave will remove that element from the original element.